# Grails application that copies and unzippes files from remote server to another remote server using SSH

Tags: grails, ssh

I'm new in JAVA\Grails\Groovy. Just began to create simple apps.
I've got a task to create grails app that:

1) shows a list of source zip files on a remote server, that is available by FTP and SSH

2) shows a list of destination remote servers with predefined target folders, that are     available only by SSH

3) after choosing source zip and dest server it copies zip to target server\folder and     unzippes. Progress bar must be shown.

4) performs some additional commands, such as ls or something like that

All configurations must by either in config files or in the database.

No information should be hardcoded in app.

Please help me to choose approach, plugin or framework.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I've used [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) a lot for SCP file transfer and remote exec using SSH and works very well. You could use it directly like you would in a Java app, by adding a dependency for the jar in `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
compile 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.51'
```

but the most trivial Google search I could manage that included "Grails" and "SSH" tells me that there's [this plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/jssh) which looks great, and [this plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/jsch-ssh2) which also looks great, and [this blog post](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2013/04/04/using-ftp-with-grails/) which looks great, and also [this plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/remote-ssh) which uses a different library but also looks great.

Those options cover the ssh and scp/sftp parts, and you can use the JDK support for Zip files, e.g. `java.util.zip.ZipFile` and the other related classes in that package, to unzip the files. The rest is pretty straightforward, but if you need more help ask more questions (one question per question).